# Incomplete response received from application on Node Js Project

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cpanel

I have tried to install the NPM packages from the cpanel. But when I try to open the website, I get the response incomplete response received from application. When i run it offline, it works properly, but when i move it to the cpanel, it gives me the incomplete response error

```
var express         = require("express"),
    app             = express(),
    mongoose        = require("mongoose"),
    flash           = require("connect-flash"),
    passport        = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy   = require("passport-local"),
    session         = require("express-session"),
    methodOverride  = require("method-override"),
    nodemailer      = require("nodemailer"),
    multer          = require("multer"),
    dotenv          = require("dotenv").config(),
    Product         = require("./models/products"),
    User            = require("./models/user");

    var mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
    mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

var indexRoutes = require("./routes/index"),
    storeRoutes = require("./routes/products");

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(flash());

//User Passport Config
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});

app.use(indexRoutes);
app.use("/store", storeRoutes);
app.use(function(req, res){
    res.send ("Error finding page")
})

const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen (port, function(){
    console.log ("Server Active");
});
```

this is what i saw in the  the `.htaccess` file. I only placed some passwords and other private info in the `.env` file

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/zenitcou/zenitcouture"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/zenitcou/nodevenv/zenitcouture/11/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile app.js
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
```

Comment: It probably has more something to do with the configuration file (such as .htaccess) rather than the actual node.js script itself.

Comment: so how do i get it fixed?

Comment: You need to share the `.htaccess` file or other configuration files that (the developer/sysadmin/tutorials?) told you. Because you're on Cpanel it is likely the apache proxy is messed up.

Comment: I've updated the question with the `.htaccess`. @willnode

Answer (score 0):

Share the response you are getting, that we can help you better

Comment: The response from the website is the incomplete response received from the application. That is what displays on the browser

Answer (score 0):

From the configuration provided, I can't tell the exact cause but I may have enough experience why you end up getting "incomplete response received from the application".

The error message might be confusing, but what it really wants to say is, nothing is actually sent from your app upon HTTP request is sent by the proxy aka. Phusion Passenger.

You can read more about what are those Passenger config in [their docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/references/config_reference/apache/)
but my gist is one of these:

1. Your app is maybe crashed due to improper configuration. I suggest using `PassengerAppEnv development` to track error messages.
2. Phusion passenger integration on Node.JS is somewhat magic, they just [don't care](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/reverse_port_binding.html) what `app.listen` port you're giving on. But it probably crashes because you set them `undefined`. Please set a fallback on your `PORT` env like `const port = process.env.PORT || 80;`
3. You set `PassengerStartupFile` as `app.js`. Is it true? (People usually set their main entry file as `server.js`. You have to make sure the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error.

For me, it was log4js. The process.send() function was undefined.
By disabling the clustering of log4js, all become fine.

To find where the error is, I proceeded with code reduction. Compiling a few lines of codes

May it helps someone